# In objective c, what is the right date format for "2011-05-10T14:30:00 0000"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsdateformatter

I know for "2011-05-10T14:30:00-0000", this "[someDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZZZ"]; " works.  But just couldn't figure out how to configure the format so it knows that the time zone has space sign before it instead of "-" sign? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1..3 capital Z [pattern](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) denotes a RFC 822 time zone. RFC 822 time zones represent the offset from GMT (or UTC), which has the following format. From the [RFC 822 standard](http://asg.web.cmu.edu/rfc/rfc822.html#sec-5.1):

```
zone             =  "UT"  / "GMT"                ; Universal Time
                                                 ; North American : UT
                 /  "EST" / "EDT"                ;  Eastern:  - 5/ - 4
                 /  "CST" / "CDT"                ;  Central:  - 6/ - 5
                 /  "MST" / "MDT"                ;  Mountain: - 7/ - 6
                 /  "PST" / "PDT"                ;  Pacific:  - 8/ - 7
                 /  1ALPHA                       ; Military: Z = UT;
                                                 ;  A:-1; (J not used)
                                                 ;  M:-12; N:+1; Y:+12
                 / ( ("+" / "-") 4DIGIT )        ; Local differential
                                                 ;  hours+min. (HHMM)
```

As you can read towards the end it expects a sign, either '+' or '-'. So, in your case, does the lack of sign implies a positive '+' or a negative '-' offset?

You could manually pre-parse your string adding the missing sign to conform to the specification.

Comment: The sample string says “0000”, so it wouldn't make a difference whether the sign were + or -. Only a non-zero offset would be ambiguous without a sign. Since the sign is required, fixing the dates' origin is the most proper fix, but this may not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace '-' with ' ' in the date format syntax (there is a space inside the single quotes)

Comment: The question is about the date formatter's expectation of sign (-/+) before the time zone; the sample string has a space, but no sign.